# PhP READING Serial port data sent from arduino

Tags: php, ubuntu, arduino, serial-port

Im trying to make something really simple, button counter, have a button on my html-php when i click it i sent data 'press' to my arduino and it makes a led flicker, so far so good, but then i want to sent the signal when i press a push button in arduino,i want to make my php read the serial port with the string "Number of clicks: N", N being the push count from arduio.

Problem here is, in arduino serial i can see he string, everything fine, but in php i do

echo fread($fp); //fp being ttyACM0

and all i get are incomplete strings example:

COMPLETE ARDUINO STRING: "Number of clicks: 15"

PHP STRING: "Ner of clic:  5"

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question what you are trying to do, but it looks like you're losing some data during the transmission. Can you post more of your code (especially the code you're running on the Arduino)?

I'd recommend sending only the value (i.e., '15' rather than 'Number of clicks: 15'), and adding the additional text in your PHP instead.